# Crontab not working @reboot with macchanger

Tags: networking, cron

In my crontab I have:

```
@reboot macchanger -r eth0
```

(changed on my root user). But the MAC address is not changing when I reboot. `macchanger -r eth0` works fine in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands have to be prefixed with the directory name and parameters have to be enclosed in double quotes. Assuming your `macchanger` resides in the regular path, create a file (with any name) in the `/etc/cron.d` directory containing:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot root sleep 15
@reboot root macchanger "-r eth0"
```

Comment: Does the file name matter?

Comment: The important thing is it's in the directory `/etc/cron.d` you can call the file anything you like. You need to create / edit it with sudo powers though.

Comment: @Alfie please note I've changed the command line by adding `root` in the middle.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, does everything look as it should here: (thanks a lot :) ) 
![Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbNq8.jpg)

Comment: Your screenshot looks perfect. Could it be the network isn't even up when cron starts? Would it be better putting macchanger into startup applications? The other option is putting sleep 15 in front of macchanger line, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: that was the problem, after adding the sleep command it works great, thanks so much!

Comment: @Alfie I'm so happy it works now... I thought I was loosing my mind :)